# Umbraco find Content by alias

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, umbraco

So far, I am fetching a content by id and works fine.

```
 var footerSection = Umbraco.TypedContent(1174);
```

Although, I am trying to have the same result by querying via document alias and it is not working:

```
 var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
    var foundFooterSection = umbracoHelper.TypedContentAtRoot().FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "footerSection");
```

I am pretty sure that document alias is "footerSection" - I have this information even from the first (successful) call but it returns null.

Any reasons that might cause this?

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your footer node is probably a descendant of root so you probably need to adjust the code a little bit.

```
var foundFooterSection = umbracoHelper
    .TypedContentAtRoot()
    .SelectMany(root => root.Descendants())
    .Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "footerSection")
    .ToList();
```